# Load customer by contact in Netsuite sriptlet

Tags: javascript, netsuite

The task is updating the subscription of the customer in Netsuite based on the email. I was able to find and update the customer but some customers do not have email at the customer level. They have an email in their contact. Now I need to find the customer based on contact. I tried various option but no luck. Can you guys please help me with the same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the contact's Internal ID, and you want to search for the customer(s) it is linked to, you can use a search like the below:

**SuiteScript 1.0**

```
nlapiSearchRecord(
  'customer',
  null,
  ['contact.internalid', 'anyof', contactID],
  [
    new nlobjSearchColumn('entityid'),
    new nlobjSearchColumn('altname'),
    new nlobjSearchColumn('email'),
    new nlobjSearchColumn('email', 'contact'),
  ]
);
```

**SuiteScript 2.0**

```
search.create({
  type: 'customer',
  filters: ['contact.internalid', 'anyof', contactID],
  columns: [
    'entityid',
    'altname',
    'email',
    'contact.email',
  ],
});
```